# How to make divs that automatically wrap to the next row

Tags: html, css

I am creating HTML voucher templates for a hotspot system and have a need for the following.

I want to print two vouchers side by side and then wrap to the the next row for the next two vouchers, the catch is that the system generating the code does not give me the freedom to assign different classes to each voucher , so the css needs to handle it automatically. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: you need to read this article first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use float:left in first row of vouchers. Hope it will help you. thanks
<div id="row1" style="float:left">
 v1_Box | v2_Box
</div>

Comment: Show us the existing snippets of HTML and CSS you have, to better show the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set a static height and width for your vouchers and display:inline-block.  They will wrap based on the size of themselves relative to their container.

```css
#container {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.voucher {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>
    <div class="voucher">hi</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer because it achieves the requirement without the use of flex box.